# Unity 3d How to create a custom wind to interact with my object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

emergency question, 
I have to do this job in a matter of days, but I'm new in Unity and what I tried  nothing is close to what I need to do. So my task is to create a tree ( without tree creator) and create a wind which interacts with that tree (without wind zone) using forces.
I tried to apply forces, but then my tree just flew away, or was spinning in circles (which was funny to watch :D like I need wind and my tree just spinnin' around)

So questions would be:
1. Which force I need to use to make tree moving side to side, like interacting with wind?
2. How to properly create a tree? Now I created with Blender tree creator, but that tree is like one object plus leaves, so I think if I use force, that tree will move like one stick, but I need it bend to sides smoothly like interacting with wind.

I hope someone can help me, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using the [Tree Creator](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Tree.html), then I think the best way would be to rig your tree and animate it "shaking." Then add those animations to your newly imported tree and call the animations as appropriate. There are alternatives, such as reading in vertices from the mesh and moving them or maybe rotating it after adjusting the [center of gravity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-centerOfMass.html), but I doubt it'll satisfy your needs. If time is a priority, you should just use the Tree Creator as that seems to be the quickest and easiest way.